# Rotation of SubView according to it's superview

Tags: ios, storyboard, subview, autorotate

I had created an application using story board with auto layout support. Now i want to add an loading view on request/response. I had created loading view by code like this

```
self=[super initWithFrame:f];
[self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.0 green:0.0 blue:0.0 alpha:0.7]];
CGPoint p=[self center];
self.activityIndicator=[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithFrame: CGRectMake(p.x-37/2, p.y-32/2, 37, 37)];
[self.activityIndicator setActivityIndicatorViewStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite];
[self addSubview:self.activityIndicator];

lblMsg=[[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(p.x-50/2,CGRectGetMaxY(self.activityIndicator.frame), 200, 30)];
lblMsg.text=@"Logging...";
lblMsg.backgroundColor=[UIColor clearColor];
lblMsg.textColor=[UIColor lightGrayColor];

[self addSubview:lblMsg];

self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
return self;
```

Now problem is that it is not performing rotation. it is always coming in portrait mode. How can i apply autorotate functionality to it.

Comment: your application is supporting only landscape mode?? or both??

Comment: ok this loading view is a separate xib file?

Comment: no i had create this by code. there is no xib of this.

Comment: ok have you written YES to should autorotate method?

Comment: it is an subview and auto rotate delegate method calls in view controller only.

Comment: try to add autorotate method to this view and implement it as per requirements may be it will help you

Answer (score 0):

may be this will help you try this

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (NSInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAllButUpsideDown;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i couldn't find where you are start animating for UIActivityIndicatorView.

```
[self.activityIndicator startAnimating];
```

One of the best framework to use for loadingView

1) https://github.com/jdg/MBProgressHUD

Answer (score 0):

You can use **`NetworkActivityIndicator`**.

When you sending the request, use

```
[self setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
```

and when the response come back, use

```
[self setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
```